# JQuery hover effect issue in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created the following snippet for my website in order to have a sliding hover effect on my images using some JQuery:-

http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/Oelm8

The JQuery function is executing correctly in the snippet, however when implemented into my existing code for my website I'm encountering a strange issue with the hover effect: when hovering over `image`, the animation 'pauses' when it reaches the cursor. I've searched around on SO for any answers to this but am struggling; any ideas what could be causing this?

Many thanks in advance.

```
<div id="summary-row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">                
            <div class="image">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h2>About Me</h2>
                    <a href=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" rel="tooltip" title="">Find out more</button></a>
                </div>
                <div class="image" rel="tooltip">
                    <a href="about.html"><img alt="Biography" class="img-responsive" src="images/about700x700.jpg" width="350" height="auto"/></a>
                </div>                 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">                
            <div class="image">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h2>Skills and Experience</h2>
                    <a href=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" rel="tooltip" title="">Find out more</button></a>
                </div>
                <div class="image" rel="tooltip">
                    <a href="portfolio.html"><img alt="Biography" class="img-responsive" src="images/skills700x700.jpg" width="350" height="auto"/></a>
                </div>                 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">                
            <div class="image">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h2>Portfolio</h2>
                    <a href=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" rel="tooltip" title="">Find out more</button></a>
                </div>
                <div class="image" rel="tooltip">
                    <a href="portfolio.html"><img alt="Biography" class="img-responsive" src="images/portfolio700x700.jpg" width="350" height="auto"/></a>
                </div>                 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">                
            <div class="image">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h2>Blog</h2>
                    <a href=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" rel="tooltip" title="">Find out more</button></a>
                </div>
                <div class="image" rel="tooltip">
                    <a href="blog.html"><img alt="Biography" class="img-responsive" src="images/blog700x700.jpg" width="350" height="auto"/></a>
                </div>                 
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery - at the foot of my HTML form:-

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();    

    $('.image').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').slideDown(300); //.fadeIn(250)
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(300); //.fadeOut(205)
        }
    ); 
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.caption {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display: none;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff !important;
    z-index:2;
}
```

[My website](http://www.jonhowlett.uk)

Comment: I've also tried rearranging the order of the links to the .js files in my HTML -as I thought that this could be affecting functionality, but no luck so far :(

Comment: I have solved the problem - I had a universal :hover transition duration set to 0.5s that was causing the animation to pause.